# Methods to use the serial port in multiple forms

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, multiple-forms

I'm designing a windows userform to interact with a microcontroller through the serial port.

The GUI includes multiple userforms which will use the same serialport. I researched how to do that and I found different ideas. Some I don't know if it works the others I'm not sure how to implement it in code. Let's say I have

Form1: Start.vb
Form2: Shield1.vb

1) Can I declare the serial port in the start userform as:

```
Public Shared SerialPort1 As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
```

And use it in the other forms ?

2) First alternative: Use a Module to declare a new Serialport

```
Module Module1
Public WithEvents mySerialPort1 As New IO.Ports.SerialPort

Private Sub mySerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, _
                                       e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) _
                                   Handles mySerialPort1.DataReceived
End Sub
End Module
```

Is this method right? If yes How do I use it in the code of my forms ? How to include the DataReceived Event in the code of the forms ?

3) Second alternative: Constructor of the Serialport in the start form and then pass the data to the other forms as mentionned in this post: [Alternate Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617283/6284963)

```
private void OnSetup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.port = new SerialPort(...);
// TODO: initialize port

Form2 f2 = new Form2(this.port);
f2.Show();
Form3 f3 = new Form3(this.port);
f3.Show();
Form4 f4 = new Form4(this.port);
f4.Show();
```

}

Are then the Events also included ? How do I use them?

4) Third alternative: Use a static class like done in this solution: 
[Alternate Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9358283/6284963)

Is the code written in C# here right ? I'm writing my programm in VB.net but I could take this as a reference.

Which is the recommended solution for a beginner ? Could you please write it in a small code if you have another suggestion or a correction ?

I apologize in advance for any ambiguity or falsly used terms.

Thanks you!

Comment: Well it depends how you structured your program if you really put functions in proper classes and modules and kept your forms only for launching those functions/sub you could simply pass it as a argument if your code isn't the best structured then it is maybe better to use the Module aproach

Comment: This is actually my first project in VB net and I'm trying to do it with the best possible structure to learn the best practice tips too. So I'm trying it with the classes. My big problem is actually the implementaion of the solutions as I seem to admire it in some beginner limbo. Can you look at the singleton class I converted in my last answer? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the "Singleton" design pattern, which ensures that only one instance of a class is created.  Here is a well-accepted template for such a class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MySerial
Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of MySerial)(Function() New
    MySerial(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)

Private Sub New()
End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As MySerial
    Get
        Return _instance.Value
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

In the `New()` method you should set up your serial port as you need to.  Then no matter where you need to use the port, you make your references to the Instance:

```
Dim singletonSerial As MySerial = MySerial.Instance
```

This is the canonical pattern to ensure that you have only one copy of an object without resorting to static classes.  It's a design pattern that dates back more than 20 years and still works great when you need exactly one copy of an object.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes the sigleton class solution seems to be the best. I'm a beginner so thank you for the info. Can please look at my next post where I found an example of a C# class and used a code converter to convert it to VB.net? Could you tell me then if the code is right ? Thanks!

Comment: Let's finish with this question before starting another, if you please.  Or just edit this one, as I might not be able to easily find your next question.

Comment: Oh I mean it is the same question. I just posted it here as  a second answer and a suggestion.

Comment: It is sort of an implemetation of your suggestion. Only I found it in C# and as much as it is similar to VB, I'm quite sure I would make a mess of the translation...

Answer (score 0):

I found this very helpful example of a sigleton C# class for serial port:
[C# Singleton Example](https://heiswayi.nrird.com/2016/csharp-simple-serialport-singleton-class)

As a beginner I used a Code converter to have it in VB.Net. Can you guys let me know if the resulting code is correct and I can use it ? Thanks a lot!!

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

Namespace HeiswayiNrird.Singleton

Public NotInheritable Class SerialPortManager

    Private Shared lazy As Lazy(Of SerialPortManager) = New Lazy(Of SerialPortManager)(() => {  }, New SerialPortManager)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As SerialPortManager
        Get
            Return lazy.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _serialPort As SerialPort

    Private _readThread As Thread

    Private _keepReading As Boolean

    Private Sub New()
        MyBase.New
        Me._serialPort = New SerialPort
        Me._readThread = Nothing
        Me._keepReading = false
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Update the serial port status to the event subscriber
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event OnStatusChanged As EventHandler(Of String)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Update received data from the serial port to the event subscriber
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event OnDataReceived As EventHandler(Of String)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Update TRUE/FALSE for the serial port connection to the event subscriber
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event OnSerialPortOpened As EventHandler(Of Boolean)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Return TRUE if the serial port is currently connected
    ''' </summary>
    Public ReadOnly Property IsOpen As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me._serialPort.IsOpen
        End Get
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Open the serial port connection using basic serial port settings
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="portname">COM1 / COM3 / COM4 / etc.</param>
    ''' <param name="baudrate">0 / 100 / 300 / 600 / 1200 / 2400 / 4800 / 9600 / 14400 / 19200 / 38400 / 56000 / 57600 / 115200 / 128000 / 256000</param>
    ''' <param name="parity">None / Odd / Even / Mark / Space</param>
    ''' <param name="databits">5 / 6 / 7 / 8</param>
    ''' <param name="stopbits">None / One / Two / OnePointFive</param>
    ''' <param name="handshake">None / XOnXOff / RequestToSend / RequestToSendXOnXOff</param>
    Public Sub Open(Optional ByVal portname As String = "COM1", Optional ByVal baudrate As Integer = 9600, Optional ByVal parity As Parity = Parity.None, Optional ByVal databits As Integer = 8, Optional ByVal stopbits As StopBits = StopBits.One, Optional ByVal handshake As Handshake = Handshake.None)
        Me.Close

        Try 
            Me._serialPort.PortName = portname
            Me._serialPort.BaudRate = baudrate
            Me._serialPort.Parity = parity
            Me._serialPort.DataBits = databits
            Me._serialPort.StopBits = stopbits
            Me._serialPort.Handshake = handshake
            Me._serialPort.ReadTimeout = 50
            Me._serialPort.WriteTimeout = 50
            Me._serialPort.Open
            Me.StartReading

        Catch  As IOException
            If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("{0} does not exist.", portname))
            End If

        Catch  As UnauthorizedAccessException
            If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("{0} already in use.", portname))
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                OnStatusChanged(Me, ("Error: " + ex.Message))
            End If

        End Try

        If Me._serialPort.IsOpen Then
            Dim sb As String = StopBits.None.ToString.Substring(0, 1)
            Select Case (Me._serialPort.StopBits)
                Case StopBits.One
                    sb = "1"
                Case StopBits.OnePointFive
                    sb = "1.5"
                Case StopBits.Two
                    sb = "2"
            End Select

            Dim p As String = Me._serialPort.Parity.ToString.Substring(0, 1)
            Dim hs As String = "No Handshake"
            'TODO: Warning!!!, inline IF is not supported ?
            (Me._serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None)
            Me._serialPort.Handshake.ToString
            If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("Connected to {0}: {1} bps, {2}{3}{4}, {5}.", Me._serialPort.PortName, Me._serialPort.BaudRate, Me._serialPort.DataBits, p, sb, hs))
            End If

            If (Not (OnSerialPortOpened) Is Nothing) Then
                OnSerialPortOpened(Me, true)
            End If

        Else
            If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("{0} already in use.", portname))
            End If

            If (Not (OnSerialPortOpened) Is Nothing) Then
                OnSerialPortOpened(Me, false)
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Close the serial port connection
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Close()
        Me.StopReading
        Me._serialPort.Close
        If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
            OnStatusChanged(Me, "Connection closed.")
        End If

        If (Not (OnSerialPortOpened) Is Nothing) Then
            OnSerialPortOpened(Me, false)
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Send/write string to the serial port
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="message"></param>
    Public Sub SendString(ByVal message As String)
        If Me._serialPort.IsOpen Then
            Try 
                Me._serialPort.Write(message)
                If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                    OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("Message sent: {0}", message))
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                If (Not (OnStatusChanged) Is Nothing) Then
                    OnStatusChanged(Me, String.Format("Failed to send string: {0}", ex.Message))
                End If

            End Try

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartReading()
        If Not Me._keepReading Then
            Me._keepReading = true
            Me._readThread = New Thread(ReadPort)
            Me._readThread.Start
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub StopReading()
        If Me._keepReading Then
            Me._keepReading = false
            Me._readThread.Join
            Me._readThread = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadPort()

        While Me._keepReading
            If Me._serialPort.IsOpen Then
                'byte[] readBuffer = new byte[_serialPort.ReadBufferSize + 1];
                Try 
                    'int count = _serialPort.Read(readBuffer, 0, _serialPort.ReadBufferSize);
                    'string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, count);
                    Dim data As String = Me._serialPort.ReadLine
                    If (Not (OnDataReceived) Is Nothing) Then
                        OnDataReceived(Me, data)
                    End If

                Catch  As TimeoutException

                End Try

            Else
                Dim waitTime As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 50)
                Thread.Sleep(waitTime)
            End If


        End While

    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Well I can't review or test this for you, but at first glance it looks as though you've translated the Singleton stuff correct. I think with my suggestion you are now on the right track, it will just take testing.